# How to convert an expression tree to a partial SQL query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

When EF or LINQ to SQL runs a query, it:

1. Builds an expression tree from the code,
2. Converts the expression tree into an SQL query,
3. Executes the query, gets the raw results from the database and converts them to the result to be used by the application.

Looking at the stack trace, I can't figure out where the second part happens.

In general, is it possible to use an existent part of EF or (preferably) LINQ to SQL to convert an `Expression` object to a partial SQL query (using Transact-SQL syntax), or I have to reinvent the wheel?

---

**Update:** a comment asks to provide an example of what I'm trying to do.

Actually, [the answer by Ryan Wright below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731905/how-to-convert-an-expression-tree-to-a-partial-sql-query/7891426#7891426) illustrates perfectly what I want to achieve as a result, except the fact that my question is specifically about *how can I do it by using existent mechanisms of .NET Framework actually used by EF and LINQ to SQL*, instead of having to reinvent the wheel and write thousands of lines of not-so-tested code myself to do the similar thing.

Here is also an example. Again, note that there is no ORM-generated code.

```
private class Product
{
    [DatabaseMapping("ProductId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseMapping("Price")]
    public int PriceInCents { get; set; }
}

private string Convert(Expression expression)
{
    // Some magic calls to .NET Framework code happen here.
    // [...]
}

private void TestConvert()
{
    Expression<Func<Product, int, int, bool>> inPriceRange =
        (Product product, int from, int to) =>
            product.PriceInCents >= from && product.PriceInCents <= to;

    string actualQueryPart = this.Convert(inPriceRange);

    Assert.AreEqual("[Price] between @from and @to", actualQueryPart);
}
```

**Where does the name `Price` come from in the expected query?**

The name can be obtained through reflection by querying the custom `DatabaseMapping` attribute of `Price` property of `Product` class.

**Where do names `@from` and `@to` come from in the expected query?**

Those names are the actual names of the parameters of the expression.

**Where does `between … and` come from in the expected query?**

This is a possible result of a binary expression. Maybe EF or LINQ to SQL would, instead of `between … and` statement, stick with `[Price] >= @from and [Price] <= @to` instead. It's ok too, it doesn't really matter since the result is logically the same (I'm not mentioning performance).

**Why there is no `where` in the expected query?**

Because nothing indicates in the `Expression` that there must be a `where` keyword. Maybe the actual expression is just one of the expressions which would be combined later with binary operators to build a larger query to prepend with a `where`.

Comment: Can you throw in an example of what you're trying to convert to what?

Comment: I opened an issue about it, join the discussion [https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13465](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13465)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The short answer seems to be that you cannot use a *part* of EF or LINQ to SQL as a shortcut to translation. You need at least a subclass of `ObjectContext` to get at the `internal protected` [QueryProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.queryprovider%28VS.100%29.aspx) property, and that means all the overhead of creating the context, including all the metadata and so on.

Assuming you are ok with that, to get a partial SQL query, for example, just the `WHERE` clause you're basically going to need the query provider and call [IQueryProvider.CreateQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549043.aspx) just as LINQ does in its implementation of [Queryable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.where.aspx). To get a more complete query you can use [ObjectQuery.ToTraceString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx).

As to where this happens, [LINQ provider basics](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/LINQProviderBasics.aspx) states generally that

> IQueryProvider returns a reference to IQueryable with the constructed expression-tree passed by the LINQ framework, which is used for further calls. In general terms, each query block is converted to a bunch of method calls. For each method call, there are some expressions involved. While creating our provider - in the method IQueryProvider.CreateQuery - we run through the expressions and fill up a filter object, which is used in the IQueryProvider.Execute method to run a query against the data store

and that

> the query can be executed in two ways, either by implementing the GetEnumerator method (defined in the IEnumerable interface) in the Query class, (which inherits from IQueryable); or it can be executed by the LINQ runtime directly

Checking EF under the debugger it's the former.

If you don't want to completely re-invent the wheel and neither EF nor LINQ to SQL are options, perhaps this series of articles would help:

- [How to: LINQ to SQL Translation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linqtosql.aspx)
- [How to: LINQ to SQL Translation - Part II](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linqtosql_2.aspx)
- [How to: LINQ to SQL Translation - Part III](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linq_to_sql3.aspx)

Here are some sources for creating a query provider that probably involve much more heavy lifting on your part to implement what you want:

- [LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx)
- [Creating custom LINQ provider using LinqExtender](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/CreatingCustomLINQProviderUsingLinqExtender.aspx)

Comment: I can not believe that there exists No finished solution to convert an Expression to a (string) SQL Statement? Searched GitHub and the NuGet gallery + Google but without any result... If someone knows a maintained solution please notify me!

Comment: I agree, a solution like that to just get an expression tree and generate raw SQL translation would be an amazing fit to the specification pattern. I wish we find something or maybe get a small group to start something.

Answer (score 59):

Yes it is possible, you can parse a LINQ expression tree using the visitor pattern. You would need to construct a query translator by subclassing ExpressionVisitor like below. By hooking into the correct points you can use the translator to construct your SQL string from your LINQ expression. Note that the code below only deals with basic where/orderby/skip/take clauses, but you can fill it out with more as needed. Hopefully it serves as a good first step.

```
public class MyQueryTranslator : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private string _orderBy = string.Empty;
    private int? _skip = null;
    private int? _take = null;
    private string _whereClause = string.Empty;

    public int? Skip
    {
        get
        {
            return _skip;
        }
    }

    public int? Take
    {
        get
        {
            return _take;
        }
    }

    public string OrderBy
    {
        get
        {
            return _orderBy;
        }
    }

    public string WhereClause
    {
        get
        {
            return _whereClause;
        }
    }

    public MyQueryTranslator()
    {
    }

    public string Translate(Expression expression)
    {
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();
        this.Visit(expression);
        _whereClause = this.sb.ToString();
        return _whereClause;
    }

    private static Expression StripQuotes(Expression e)
    {
        while (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
        {
            e = ((UnaryExpression)e).Operand;
        }
        return e;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
    {
        if (m.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable) && m.Method.Name == "Where")
        {
            this.Visit(m.Arguments[0]);
            LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression)StripQuotes(m.Arguments[1]);
            this.Visit(lambda.Body);
            return m;
        }
        else if (m.Method.Name == "Take")
        {
            if (this.ParseTakeExpression(m))
            {
                Expression nextExpression = m.Arguments[0];
                return this.Visit(nextExpression);
            }
        }
        else if (m.Method.Name == "Skip")
        {
            if (this.ParseSkipExpression(m))
            {
                Expression nextExpression = m.Arguments[0];
                return this.Visit(nextExpression);
            }
        }
        else if (m.Method.Name == "OrderBy")
        {
            if (this.ParseOrderByExpression(m, "ASC"))
            {
                Expression nextExpression = m.Arguments[0];
                return this.Visit(nextExpression);
            }
        }
        else if (m.Method.Name == "OrderByDescending")
        {
            if (this.ParseOrderByExpression(m, "DESC"))
            {
                Expression nextExpression = m.Arguments[0];
                return this.Visit(nextExpression);
            }
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The method '{0}' is not supported", m.Method.Name));
    }

    protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression u)
    {
        switch (u.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Not:
                sb.Append(" NOT ");
                this.Visit(u.Operand);
                break;
            case ExpressionType.Convert:
                this.Visit(u.Operand);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The unary operator '{0}' is not supported", u.NodeType));
        }
        return u;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
    {
        sb.Append("(");
        this.Visit(b.Left);

        switch (b.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.And:
                sb.Append(" AND ");
                break;

            case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
                sb.Append(" AND ");
                break;

            case ExpressionType.Or:
                sb.Append(" OR ");
                break;

            case ExpressionType.OrElse:
                sb.Append(" OR ");
                break;

            case ExpressionType.Equal:
                if (IsNullConstant(b.Right))
                {
                    sb.Append(" IS ");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(" = ");
                }
                break;

            case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                if (IsNullConstant(b.Right))
                {
                    sb.Append(" IS NOT ");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(" <> ");
                }
                break;

            case ExpressionType.LessThan:
                sb.Append(" < ");
                break;

            case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
                sb.Append(" <= ");
                break;

            case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
                sb.Append(" > ");
                break;

            case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                sb.Append(" >= ");
                break;

            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The binary operator '{0}' is not supported", b.NodeType));

        }

        this.Visit(b.Right);
        sb.Append(")");
        return b;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
    {
        IQueryable q = c.Value as IQueryable;

        if (q == null && c.Value == null)
        {
            sb.Append("NULL");
        }
        else if (q == null)
        {
            switch (Type.GetTypeCode(c.Value.GetType()))
            {
                case TypeCode.Boolean:
                    sb.Append(((bool)c.Value) ? 1 : 0);
                    break;

                case TypeCode.String:
                    sb.Append("'");
                    sb.Append(c.Value);
                    sb.Append("'");
                    break;

                case TypeCode.DateTime:
                    sb.Append("'");
                    sb.Append(c.Value);
                    sb.Append("'");
                    break;

                case TypeCode.Object:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The constant for '{0}' is not supported", c.Value));

                default:
                    sb.Append(c.Value);
                    break;
            }
        }

        return c;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression m)
    {
        if (m.Expression != null && m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
        {
            sb.Append(m.Member.Name);
            return m;
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The member '{0}' is not supported", m.Member.Name));
    }

    protected bool IsNullConstant(Expression exp)
    {
        return (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant && ((ConstantExpression)exp).Value == null);
    }

    private bool ParseOrderByExpression(MethodCallExpression expression, string order)
    {
        UnaryExpression unary = (UnaryExpression)expression.Arguments[1];
        LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)unary.Operand;

        lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)Evaluator.PartialEval(lambdaExpression);

        MemberExpression body = lambdaExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_orderBy))
            {
                _orderBy = string.Format("{0} {1}", body.Member.Name, order);
            }
            else
            {
                _orderBy = string.Format("{0}, {1} {2}", _orderBy, body.Member.Name, order);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool ParseTakeExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
    {
        ConstantExpression sizeExpression = (ConstantExpression)expression.Arguments[1];

        int size;
        if (int.TryParse(sizeExpression.Value.ToString(), out size))
        {
            _take = size;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool ParseSkipExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
    {
        ConstantExpression sizeExpression = (ConstantExpression)expression.Arguments[1];

        int size;
        if (int.TryParse(sizeExpression.Value.ToString(), out size))
        {
            _skip = size;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then visit the expression by calling:

```
var translator = new MyQueryTranslator();
string whereClause = translator.Translate(expression);
```

Comment: While a good start this appears to be missing any string manipulation or the ability to compare strings. E.g. Contains, StartsWith. Again, good start.

Comment: I was looking for a way to extract only the 'Skip' and 'Take' within the `Query()` override of a custom `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainService` class (RIA Service), and this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Where is this "Evaluator" class located?

Comment: Evaluator is needed to resolve references to local variables in your expressions. I've used implementation from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/08/01/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-iii.aspx). Also it is worth while partially evaluate expression earlier (i.e. in the Translate method, and remove the call to Evaluator from ParseOrderByExpression like this):
         `public string Translate(Expression expression) {
            expression = Evaluator.PartialEval(expression);`

Comment: THX man this is just what i needed.  I have added contain and i will also add Any 

Comment: I'm getting an error when try to translate `DateTime.Now`. For intance: `t => t.Name == "NAME" && t.OpeningDate == DateTime.Now`. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Anyone who is going to use it to generate a where clause to append it to SQL , please note that the single quotes are not escaped in the resulting clause. For that change `sb.Append(c.Value);` to `sb.Append(c.Value.ToString.Replace('"","''"));` in the `VisitConstant`method

Comment: For those asking about the "Evaluator", the provided link by @Peter is broken, here is where you can find it https://github.com/mattwar/iqtoolkit/issues/18 check part III

Comment: the Evaluator class can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308124/force-a-net-expression-to-use-current-value. Found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62490794/6509536)  credit to [Legacy Code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5209014/legacy-code)

Comment: Does this provide the appropriate split of on data layer fields an non-data layer fields?
eg: have a class with 10 properties, 5 are on the data layer, 5 aren't.  a "lambda predicate" uses 3 data layer fields, and 2 non-data layer fields.  can i get the 3 SqlParameters and the "WHERE" clause, as well as a newly created predicate of the remaining 2 fields that aren't on the data layer?

Answer (score 8):

After searching for hours for an implementation of an Expression tree to SQL converter, I did not found anything usefull or free or somehow working with .NET Core.
Then I found this. Thank you **Ryan Wright**.
I took his code and modified it a bit to fit my needs. Now I am giving it back to the community.

Current version can do the following:

#### Bulk update

```cs
            int rowCount = context
                .Users
                .Where(x => x.Status == UserStatus.Banned)
                .Update(x => new
                {
                    DisplayName = "Bad Guy"
                });
```

This will produce the following sql

```sql
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar
DECLARE @p1 Int
SET @p0 = 'Bad Guy'
SET @p1 = 3
UPDATE [Users]
SET [DisplayName] = @p0
WHERE ( [Status] = @p1 )
```

#### Bulk delete

```cs
            int rowCount = context
                .Users
                .Where(x => x.UniqueName.EndsWith("012"))
                .Delete();
```

The produced sql

```sql
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar
SET @p0 = '%012'
DELETE
FROM [Users]
WHERE [UniqueName] LIKE @p0
```

#### Outputing SQL Statements

```cs
            string sql = context
                .Users
                .Where(x => x.Status == UserStatus.LockedOut)
                .OrderBy(x => x.UniqueName)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.LastLogin)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.UniqueName,
                    x.Email
                })
                .ToSqlString();
```

This produces the sql

```sql
DECLARE @p0 Int
SET @p0 = 4
SELECT [UniqueName], [Email]
FROM [Users]
WHERE ( [Status] = @p0 )
ORDER BY [LastLogin] DESC, [UniqueName] ASC
```

Another example

```cs
            string sql = context
                .Users
                .Where(x => x.Status == UserStatus.LockedOut)
                .OrderBy(x => x.UniqueName)
                .ThenByDescending(x => x.LastLogin)
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.UniqueName,
                    x.Email,
                    x.LastLogin
                })
                .Take(4)
                .Skip(3)
                .Distinct()
                .ToSqlString();
```

The sql

```sql
DECLARE @p0 Int
SET @p0 = 4
SELECT DISTINCT [UniqueName], [Email], [LastLogin]
FROM [Users]
WHERE ( [Status] = @p0 )
ORDER BY [LastLogin] DESC, [UniqueName] ASC OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 4 ROWS ONLY
```

Another example with a local variable

```cs
            string name ="venom";

            string sql = context
                .Users
                .Where(x => x.LastLogin == DateTime.UtcNow && x.UniqueName.Contains(name))
                .Select(x => x.Email)
                .ToSqlString();
```

The produced sql

```sql
DECLARE @p0 DateTime
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar
SET @p0 = '20.06.2020 19:23:46'
SET @p1 = '%venom%'
SELECT [Email]
FROM [Users]
WHERE ( ( [LastLogin] = @p0 ) AND [UniqueName] LIKE @p1 )
```

The **SimpleExpressionToSQL** class itself can be used directly

```cs
var simpleExpressionToSQL = new SimpleExpressionToSQL(queryable);
simpleExpressionToSQL.ExecuteNonQuery(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);
```

#### The code

The evaluator used here come from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308124/force-a-net-expression-to-use-current-value)

**SimpleExpressionToSQL**

```cs
    public class SimpleExpressionToSQL : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        /*
         * Original By Ryan Wright: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731905/how-to-convert-an-expression-tree-to-a-partial-sql-query
         */

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        private readonly List<string> _groupBy = new List<string>();

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        private readonly List<string> _orderBy = new List<string>();

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        private readonly List<SqlParameter> _parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        private readonly List<string> _select = new List<string>();

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        private readonly List<string> _update = new List<string>();

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        private readonly List<string> _where = new List<string>();

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        private int? _skip;

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
        private int? _take;

        public SimpleExpressionToSQL(IQueryable queryable)
        {
            if (queryable is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queryable));
            }

            Expression expression = queryable.Expression;
            Visit(expression);
            Type entityType = (GetEntityType(expression) as IQueryable).ElementType;
            TableName = queryable.GetTableName(entityType);
            DbContext = queryable.GetDbContext();
        }

        public string CommandText => BuildSqlStatement().Join(Environment.NewLine);

        public DbContext DbContext { get; private set; }

        public string From => $"FROM [{TableName}]";

        public string GroupBy => _groupBy.Count == 0 ? null : "GROUP BY " + _groupBy.Join(", ");
        public bool IsDelete { get; private set; } = false;
        public bool IsDistinct { get; private set; }
        public string OrderBy => BuildOrderByStatement().Join(" ");
        public SqlParameter[] Parameters => _parameters.ToArray();
        public string Select => BuildSelectStatement().Join(" ");
        public int? Skip => _skip;
        public string TableName { get; private set; }
        public int? Take => _take;
        public string Update => "SET " + _update.Join(", ");

        public string Where => _where.Count == 0 ? null : "WHERE " + _where.Join(" ");

        public static implicit operator string(SimpleExpressionToSQL simpleExpression) => simpleExpression.ToString();

        public int ExecuteNonQuery(IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)
        {
            DbConnection connection = DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
            using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = CommandText;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);

#if DEBUG
                Debug.WriteLine(ToString());
#endif

                if (command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    command.Connection.Open();

                using (DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel))
                {
                    command.Transaction = transaction;
                    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    transaction.Commit();

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task<int> ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)
        {
            DbConnection connection = DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
            using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = CommandText;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters);

#if DEBUG
                Debug.WriteLine(ToString());
#endif

                if (command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    await command.Connection.OpenAsync();

                using (DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel))
                {
                    command.Transaction = transaction;
                    int result = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    transaction.Commit();

                    return result;
                }
            }
        }

        public override string ToString() =>
            BuildDeclaration()
                .Union(BuildSqlStatement())
                .Join(Environment.NewLine);

        protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
        {
            _where.Add("(");
            Visit(binaryExpression.Left);

            switch (binaryExpression.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.And:
                    _where.Add("AND");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
                    _where.Add("AND");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.Or:
                case ExpressionType.OrElse:
                    _where.Add("OR");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.Equal:
                    if (IsNullConstant(binaryExpression.Right))
                    {
                        _where.Add("IS");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _where.Add("=");
                    }
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                    if (IsNullConstant(binaryExpression.Right))
                    {
                        _where.Add("IS NOT");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _where.Add("<>");
                    }
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.LessThan:
                    _where.Add("<");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
                    _where.Add("<=");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
                    _where.Add(">");
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    _where.Add(">=");
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The binary operator '{0}' is not supported", binaryExpression.NodeType));
            }

            Visit(binaryExpression.Right);
            _where.Add(")");
            return binaryExpression;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression constantExpression)
        {
            switch (constantExpression.Value)
            {
                case null when constantExpression.Value == null:
                    _where.Add("NULL");
                    break;

                default:

                    if (constantExpression.Type.CanConvertToSqlDbType())
                    {
                        _where.Add(CreateParameter(constantExpression.Value).ParameterName);
                    }

                    break;
            }

            return constantExpression;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression memberExpression)
        {
            Expression VisitMemberLocal(Expression expression)
            {
                switch (expression.NodeType)
                {
                    case ExpressionType.Parameter:
                        _where.Add($"[{memberExpression.Member.Name}]");
                        return memberExpression;

                    case ExpressionType.Constant:
                        _where.Add(CreateParameter(GetValue(memberExpression)).ParameterName);

                        return memberExpression;

                    case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                        _where.Add(CreateParameter(GetValue(memberExpression)).ParameterName);

                        return memberExpression;
                }

                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The member '{0}' is not supported", memberExpression.Member.Name));
            }

            if (memberExpression.Expression == null)
            {
                return VisitMemberLocal(memberExpression);
            }

            return VisitMemberLocal(memberExpression.Expression);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
        {
            switch (methodCallExpression.Method.Name)
            {
                case nameof(Queryable.Where) when methodCallExpression.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable):

                    Visit(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]);
                    var lambda = (LambdaExpression)StripQuotes(methodCallExpression.Arguments[1]);
                    Visit(lambda.Body);

                    return methodCallExpression;

                case nameof(Queryable.Select):
                    return ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, _select);

                case nameof(Queryable.GroupBy):
                    return ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, _groupBy);

                case nameof(Queryable.Take):
                    return ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, ref _take);

                case nameof(Queryable.Skip):
                    return ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, ref _skip);

                case nameof(Queryable.OrderBy):
                case nameof(Queryable.ThenBy):
                    return ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, _orderBy, "ASC");

                case nameof(Queryable.OrderByDescending):
                case nameof(Queryable.ThenByDescending):
                    return ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, _orderBy, "DESC");

                case nameof(Queryable.Distinct):
                    IsDistinct = true;
                    return Visit(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]);

                case nameof(string.StartsWith):
                    _where.AddRange(ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, methodCallExpression.Object));
                    _where.Add("LIKE");
                    _where.Add(CreateParameter(GetValue(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).ToString() + "%").ParameterName);
                    return methodCallExpression.Arguments[0];

                case nameof(string.EndsWith):
                    _where.AddRange(ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, methodCallExpression.Object));
                    _where.Add("LIKE");
                    _where.Add(CreateParameter("%" + GetValue(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).ToString()).ParameterName);
                    return methodCallExpression.Arguments[0];

                case nameof(string.Contains):
                    _where.AddRange(ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, methodCallExpression.Object));
                    _where.Add("LIKE");
                    _where.Add(CreateParameter("%" + GetValue(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]).ToString() + "%").ParameterName);
                    return methodCallExpression.Arguments[0];

                case nameof(Extensions.ToSqlString):
                    return Visit(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]);

                case nameof(Extensions.Delete):
                case nameof(Extensions.DeleteAsync):
                    IsDelete = true;
                    return Visit(methodCallExpression.Arguments[0]);

                case nameof(Extensions.Update):
                    return ParseExpression(methodCallExpression, _update);

                default:
                    if (methodCallExpression.Object != null)
                    {
                        _where.Add(CreateParameter(GetValue(methodCallExpression)).ParameterName);
                        return methodCallExpression;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException($"The method '{methodCallExpression.Method.Name}' is not supported");
        }

        protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression unaryExpression)
        {
            switch (unaryExpression.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Not:
                    _where.Add("NOT");
                    Visit(unaryExpression.Operand);
                    break;

                case ExpressionType.Convert:
                    Visit(unaryExpression.Operand);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"The unary operator '{unaryExpression.NodeType}' is not supported");
            }
            return unaryExpression;
        }

        private static Expression StripQuotes(Expression expression)
        {
            while (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
            {
                expression = ((UnaryExpression)expression).Operand;
            }
            return expression;
        }

        [SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE0011:Add braces", Justification = "Easier to read")]
        private IEnumerable<string> BuildDeclaration()
        {
            if (Parameters.Length == 0)                        /**/    yield break;
            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in Parameters)     /**/    yield return $"DECLARE {parameter.ParameterName} {parameter.SqlDbType}";

            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in Parameters)     /**/
                if (parameter.SqlDbType.RequiresQuotes())      /**/    yield return $"SET {parameter.ParameterName} = '{parameter.SqlValue?.ToString().Replace("'", "''") ?? "NULL"}'";
                else                                           /**/    yield return $"SET {parameter.ParameterName} = {parameter.SqlValue}";
        }

        [SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE0011:Add braces", Justification = "Easier to read")]
        private IEnumerable<string> BuildOrderByStatement()
        {
            if (Skip.HasValue && _orderBy.Count == 0)                       /**/   yield return "ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)";
            else if (_orderBy.Count == 0)                                   /**/   yield break;
            else if (_groupBy.Count > 0 && _orderBy[0].StartsWith("[Key]")) /**/   yield return "ORDER BY " + _groupBy.Join(", ");
            else                                                            /**/   yield return "ORDER BY " + _orderBy.Join(", ");

            if (Skip.HasValue && Take.HasValue)                             /**/   yield return $"OFFSET {Skip} ROWS FETCH NEXT {Take} ROWS ONLY";
            else if (Skip.HasValue && !Take.HasValue)                       /**/   yield return $"OFFSET {Skip} ROWS";
        }

        [SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE0011:Add braces", Justification = "Easier to read")]
        private IEnumerable<string> BuildSelectStatement()
        {
            yield return "SELECT";

            if (IsDistinct)                                 /**/    yield return "DISTINCT";

            if (Take.HasValue && !Skip.HasValue)            /**/    yield return $"TOP ({Take.Value})";

            if (_select.Count == 0 && _groupBy.Count > 0)   /**/    yield return _groupBy.Select(x => $"MAX({x})").Join(", ");
            else if (_select.Count == 0)                    /**/    yield return "*";
            else                                            /**/    yield return _select.Join(", ");
        }

        [SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE0011:Add braces", Justification = "Easier to read")]
        private IEnumerable<string> BuildSqlStatement()
        {
            if (IsDelete)                   /**/   yield return "DELETE";
            else if (_update.Count > 0)     /**/   yield return $"UPDATE [{TableName}]";
            else                            /**/   yield return Select;

            if (_update.Count == 0)         /**/   yield return From;
            else if (_update.Count > 0)     /**/   yield return Update;

            if (Where != null)              /**/   yield return Where;
            if (GroupBy != null)            /**/   yield return GroupBy;
            if (OrderBy != null)            /**/   yield return OrderBy;
        }

        private SqlParameter CreateParameter(object value)
        {
            string parameterName = $"@p{_parameters.Count}";

            var parameter = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = parameterName,
                Value = value
            };

            _parameters.Add(parameter);

            return parameter;
        }

        private object GetEntityType(Expression expression)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                switch (expression)
                {
                    case ConstantExpression constantExpression:
                        return constantExpression.Value;

                    case MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression:
                        expression = methodCallExpression.Arguments[0];
                        continue;

                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetNewExpressionString(NewExpression newExpression, string appendString = null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newExpression.Members.Count; i++)
            {
                if (newExpression.Arguments[i].NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
                {
                    yield return
                        appendString == null ?
                        $"[{newExpression.Members[i].Name}]" :
                        $"[{newExpression.Members[i].Name}] {appendString}";
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return
                        appendString == null ?
                        $"[{newExpression.Members[i].Name}] = {CreateParameter(GetValue(newExpression.Arguments[i])).ParameterName}" :
                        $"[{newExpression.Members[i].Name}] = {CreateParameter(GetValue(newExpression.Arguments[i])).ParameterName}";
                }
            }
        }

        private object GetValue(Expression expression)
        {
            object GetMemberValue(MemberInfo memberInfo, object container = null)
            {
                switch (memberInfo)
                {
                    case FieldInfo fieldInfo:
                        return fieldInfo.GetValue(container);

                    case PropertyInfo propertyInfo:
                        return propertyInfo.GetValue(container);

                    default: return null;
                }
            }

            switch (expression)
            {
                case ConstantExpression constantExpression:
                    return constantExpression.Value;

                case MemberExpression memberExpression when memberExpression.Expression is ConstantExpression constantExpression:
                    return GetMemberValue(memberExpression.Member, constantExpression.Value);

                case MemberExpression memberExpression when memberExpression.Expression is null: // static
                    return GetMemberValue(memberExpression.Member);

                case MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression:
                    return Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke();

                case null:
                    return null;
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        private bool IsNullConstant(Expression expression) => expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant && ((ConstantExpression)expression).Value == null;

        private IEnumerable<string> ParseExpression(Expression parent, Expression body, string appendString = null)
        {
            switch (body)
            {
                case MemberExpression memberExpression:
                    return appendString == null ?
                        new string[] { $"[{memberExpression.Member.Name}]" } :
                        new string[] { $"[{memberExpression.Member.Name}] {appendString}" };

                case NewExpression newExpression:
                    return GetNewExpressionString(newExpression, appendString);

                case ParameterExpression parameterExpression when parent is LambdaExpression lambdaExpression && lambdaExpression.ReturnType == parameterExpression.Type:
                    return new string[0];

                case ConstantExpression constantExpression:
                    return constantExpression
                        .Type
                        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                        .Select(x => $"[{x.Name}] = {CreateParameter(x.GetValue(constantExpression.Value)).ParameterName}");
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        private Expression ParseExpression(MethodCallExpression expression, List<string> commandList, string appendString = null)
        {
            var unary = (UnaryExpression)expression.Arguments[1];
            var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)unary.Operand;

            lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)Evaluator.PartialEval(lambdaExpression);

            commandList.AddRange(ParseExpression(lambdaExpression, lambdaExpression.Body, appendString));

            return Visit(expression.Arguments[0]);
        }

        private Expression ParseExpression(MethodCallExpression expression, ref int? size)
        {
            var sizeExpression = (ConstantExpression)expression.Arguments[1];

            if (int.TryParse(sizeExpression.Value.ToString(), out int value))
            {
                size = value;
                return Visit(expression.Arguments[0]);
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

*I will post the extension in the comments*
Edit: too long for the comment... I'll add another answer.

#### Use it with caution on production

Feel free to make a Nuget package out of it :)

Comment: Hey man, do you have any full working example of this? I am having troubles to combine them all together. What is context and why it have Users? How could I use this on a simple class with status enabled bool?

Comment: @SecretaryOfEducation The context is just a DBContext instance.

Answer (score 7):

It isn't complete, but here are some thoughts for you to groove on if you come by this later:

```
    private string CreateWhereClause(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        StringBuilder p = new StringBuilder(predicate.Body.ToString());
        var pName = predicate.Parameters.First();
        p.Replace(pName.Name + ".", "");
        p.Replace("==", "=");
        p.Replace("AndAlso", "and");
        p.Replace("OrElse", "or");
        p.Replace("\"", "\'");
        return p.ToString();
    }

    private string AddWhereToSelectCommand(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, int maxCount = 0)
    {           
        string command = string.Format("{0} where {1}", CreateSelectCommand(maxCount), CreateWhereClause(predicate));
        return command;
    }

    private string CreateSelectCommand(int maxCount = 0)
    {
        string selectMax = maxCount > 0 ? "TOP " + maxCount.ToString() + " * " : "*";
        string command = string.Format("Select {0} from {1}", selectMax, _tableName);
        return command;
    }
```

Comment: I feel your answer deserved more attention here.
But you might find problems with method calls like, with the expression `(f)=> f.SomeList.Where((g)=> g.Epicness > 30)`
Another thing to notice is that `(f)=> f.Name != Environtment.MachineName` will output something like "f.Name != 'Environment.MachineName'", this could be counter productive.

Answer (score 6):

In Linq2SQL you can use:

```
var cmd = DataContext.GetCommand(expression);
var sqlQuery = cmd.CommandText;
```

Comment: Your sample is inexact. The argument of `GetCommand` is not an `Expression`, but an `IQueryable`, and building an `IQueryable` requires to have an `IQueryProvider`. So the problem remain the same.

Comment: So you want to create a SQL query from an expression without a `QueryProvider`?

Comment: More precisely, I want to create a partial SQL query from an expression without having to add tables from database to EF/Linq2SQL. If I understood well, query providers used by Linq2SQL depend on those tables. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You basically have to re-invent the wheel. The QueryProvider is the thing that does the translation from expression trees to it's store native syntax. It's the thing that's going to handle special situations as well like string.Contains(), string.StartsWith(), and all the specialty functions that handle it. It's also going to handle metadata lookups in the various layers of your ORM (*.edml in the case of database-first or model-first Entity Framework). There are already examples and frameworks for building out SQL commands. But what you're looking for sounds like a partial solution.

Also understand that table/view metadata is required to correctly determine what is legal. The query providers are quite complex and do a lot of work for you beyond making simple expression tree conversions into SQL.

In response to your where does the second part happen. The second part happens during enumeration of the IQueryable. IQueryables are also IEnumerables and ultimately when GetEnumerator is called it in turn is going to call the query provider with the expression tree which is going to use its metadata to produce a sql command. It's not exactly what happens, but it should get the idea accross.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code:

```
var query = from c in Customers
            select c;

string sql = ((ObjectQuery)query).ToTraceString();
```

Have a look at the following information: [Retrieving the SQL generated by the Entity Provider](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/dsakai/2010/11/retrieving-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-provider-for-teradata).

Comment: For EF at least, doesn't that require he establish an `ObjectContext` or `DbContext` first (which means setting up just about everything) and not just a *part* of EF.

Answer (score 2):

**Extensions** for the **SimpleExpressionToSQL** class

```cs
    public static class Extensions
    {
        private static readonly MethodInfo _deleteMethod;
        private static readonly MethodInfo _deleteMethodAsync;
        private static readonly MethodInfo _toSqlStringMethod;
        private static readonly MethodInfo _updateMethod;
        private static readonly MethodInfo _updateMethodAsync;

        static Extensions()
        {
            Type extensionType = typeof(Extensions);

            _deleteMethod = extensionType.GetMethod(nameof(Extensions.Delete), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            _updateMethod = extensionType.GetMethod(nameof(Extensions.Update), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

            _deleteMethodAsync = extensionType.GetMethod(nameof(Extensions.DeleteAsync), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
            _updateMethodAsync = extensionType.GetMethod(nameof(Extensions.Update), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

            _toSqlStringMethod = extensionType.GetMethod(nameof(Extensions.ToSqlString), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        }

        public static bool CanConvertToSqlDbType(this Type type) => type.ToSqlDbTypeInternal().HasValue;

        public static int Delete<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
        {
            var simpleExpressionToSQL = new SimpleExpressionToSQL(queryable.AppendCall(_deleteMethod));
            return simpleExpressionToSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public static async Task<int> DeleteAsync<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
        {
            var simpleExpressionToSQL = new SimpleExpressionToSQL(queryable.AppendCall(_deleteMethodAsync));
            return await simpleExpressionToSQL.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }

        public static string GetTableName<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet) where TEntity : class
        {
            DbContext context = dbSet.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;
            IModel model = context.Model;
            IEntityType entityTypeOfFooBar = model
                .GetEntityTypes()
                .First(t => t.ClrType == typeof(TEntity));

            IAnnotation tableNameAnnotation = entityTypeOfFooBar.GetAnnotation("Relational:TableName");

            return tableNameAnnotation.Value.ToString();
        }

        public static string GetTableName(this IQueryable query, Type entity)
        {
            QueryCompiler compiler = query.Provider.GetValueOfField<QueryCompiler>("_queryCompiler");
            IModel model = compiler.GetValueOfField<IModel>("_model");
            IEntityType entityTypeOfFooBar = model
                .GetEntityTypes()
                .First(t => t.ClrType == entity);

            IAnnotation tableNameAnnotation = entityTypeOfFooBar.GetAnnotation("Relational:TableName");

            return tableNameAnnotation.Value.ToString();
        }

        public static SqlDbType ToSqlDbType(this Type type) =>
            type.ToSqlDbTypeInternal() ?? throw new InvalidCastException($"Unable to cast from '{type}' to '{typeof(DbType)}'.");

        public static string ToSqlString<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable) => new SimpleExpressionToSQL(queryable.AppendCall(_toSqlStringMethod));

        public static int Update<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
        {
            var simpleExpressionToSQL = new SimpleExpressionToSQL(queryable.AppendCall(_updateMethod, selector));
            return simpleExpressionToSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public static async Task<int> UpdateAsync<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
        {
            var simpleExpressionToSQL = new SimpleExpressionToSQL(queryable.AppendCall(_updateMethodAsync, selector));
            return await simpleExpressionToSQL.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }

        internal static DbContext GetDbContext(this IQueryable query)
        {
            QueryCompiler compiler = query.Provider.GetValueOfField<QueryCompiler>("_queryCompiler");
            RelationalQueryContextFactory queryContextFactory = compiler.GetValueOfField<RelationalQueryContextFactory>("_queryContextFactory");
            QueryContextDependencies dependencies = queryContextFactory.GetValueOfField<QueryContextDependencies>("_dependencies");

            return dependencies.CurrentContext.Context;
        }

        internal static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator) => string.Join(separator, values);

        internal static bool RequiresQuotes(this SqlDbType sqlDbType)
        {
            switch (sqlDbType)
            {
                case SqlDbType.Char:
                case SqlDbType.Date:
                case SqlDbType.DateTime:
                case SqlDbType.DateTime2:
                case SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset:
                case SqlDbType.NChar:
                case SqlDbType.NText:
                case SqlDbType.Time:
                case SqlDbType.SmallDateTime:
                case SqlDbType.Text:
                case SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier:
                case SqlDbType.Timestamp:
                case SqlDbType.VarChar:
                case SqlDbType.Xml:
                case SqlDbType.Variant:
                case SqlDbType.NVarChar:
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        internal static unsafe string ToCamelCase(this string value)
        {
            if (value == null || value.Length == 0)
            {
                return value;
            }

            string result = string.Copy(value);

            fixed (char* chr = result)
            {
                char valueChar = *chr;
                *chr = char.ToLowerInvariant(valueChar);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static IQueryable<TResult> AppendCall<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, MethodInfo methodInfo, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector)
        {
            MethodInfo methodInfoGeneric = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), typeof(TResult));
            MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(methodInfoGeneric, queryable.Expression, selector);

            return new EntityQueryable<TResult>(queryable.Provider as IAsyncQueryProvider, methodCallExpression);
        }

        private static IQueryable<T> AppendCall<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        {
            MethodInfo methodInfoGeneric = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));
            MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(methodInfoGeneric, queryable.Expression);

            return new EntityQueryable<T>(queryable.Provider as IAsyncQueryProvider, methodCallExpression);
        }

        private static T GetValueOfField<T>(this object obj, string name)
        {
            FieldInfo field = obj
                .GetType()
                .GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            return (T)field.GetValue(obj);
        }

        [SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE0011:Add braces", Justification = "Easier to read than with Allman braces")]
        private static SqlDbType? ToSqlDbTypeInternal(this Type type)
        {
            if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) is Type nullableType)
                return nullableType.ToSqlDbTypeInternal();

            if (type.IsEnum)
                return Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type).ToSqlDbTypeInternal();

            if (type == typeof(long))            /**/                return SqlDbType.BigInt;
            if (type == typeof(byte[]))          /**/                return SqlDbType.VarBinary;
            if (type == typeof(bool))            /**/                return SqlDbType.Bit;
            if (type == typeof(string))          /**/                return SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            if (type == typeof(DateTime))        /**/                return SqlDbType.DateTime2;
            if (type == typeof(decimal))         /**/                return SqlDbType.Decimal;
            if (type == typeof(double))          /**/                return SqlDbType.Float;
            if (type == typeof(int))             /**/                return SqlDbType.Int;
            if (type == typeof(float))           /**/                return SqlDbType.Real;
            if (type == typeof(Guid))            /**/                return SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier;
            if (type == typeof(short))           /**/                return SqlDbType.SmallInt;
            if (type == typeof(object))          /**/                return SqlDbType.Variant;
            if (type == typeof(DateTimeOffset))  /**/                return SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset;
            if (type == typeof(TimeSpan))        /**/                return SqlDbType.Time;
            if (type == typeof(byte))            /**/                return SqlDbType.TinyInt;

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but it looks like it might be close:

```
string[] companies = { "Consolidated Messenger", "Alpine Ski House", "Southridge Video", "City Power & Light",
                   "Coho Winery", "Wide World Importers", "Graphic Design Institute", "Adventure Works",
                   "Humongous Insurance", "Woodgrove Bank", "Margie's Travel", "Northwind Traders",
                   "Blue Yonder Airlines", "Trey Research", "The Phone Company",
                   "Wingtip Toys", "Lucerne Publishing", "Fourth Coffee" };

// The IQueryable data to query.
IQueryable<String> queryableData = companies.AsQueryable<string>();

// Compose the expression tree that represents the parameter to the predicate.
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "company");

// ***** Where(company => (company.ToLower() == "coho winery" || company.Length > 16)) *****
// Create an expression tree that represents the expression 'company.ToLower() == "coho winery"'.
Expression left = Expression.Call(pe, typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
Expression right = Expression.Constant("coho winery");
Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);

// Create an expression tree that represents the expression 'company.Length > 16'.
left = Expression.Property(pe, typeof(string).GetProperty("Length"));
right = Expression.Constant(16, typeof(int));
Expression e2 = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);

// Combine the expression trees to create an expression tree that represents the
// expression '(company.ToLower() == "coho winery" || company.Length > 16)'.
Expression predicateBody = Expression.OrElse(e1, e2);

// Create an expression tree that represents the expression
// 'queryableData.Where(company => (company.ToLower() == "coho winery" || company.Length > 16))'
MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },
    queryableData.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(predicateBody, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
// ***** End Where *****

// ***** OrderBy(company => company) *****
// Create an expression tree that represents the expression
// 'whereCallExpression.OrderBy(company => company)'
MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "OrderBy",
    new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType, queryableData.ElementType },
    whereCallExpression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(pe, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));
// ***** End OrderBy *****

// Create an executable query from the expression tree.
IQueryable<string> results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(orderByCallExpression);

// Enumerate the results.
foreach (string company in results)
    Console.WriteLine(company);
```