# Unable to resolve expression constants from variable

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30308124/force-a-net-expression-to-use-current-value) marked answer, I've copied `Evaluator.cs` into my project for partial evaluations to be able to resolve local variables of the expression. Regardless, it seems I'm missing something because for me it does not simplify the expression and the constants are kept as the original expression as an instance of an anonymous class generated by the compiler:

My VisitMember method of my visitor looks like this:

```
protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression m)
{
    if (m.Expression != null && m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
    {
        sqlBuilder.AddColumn(m.Member.GetFieldName());
        return m;
    }
    else if (m.Expression != null && m.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
    {
        var partialEval = Evaluator.PartialEval(m.Expression);
        this.Visit(partialEval);
        return m;
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The member '{0}' is not supported", m.Member.Name));
}
```

**UPDATE**: For better understanding of whay I'm trying to do, here's a unit test I'm performing in order to test that the output sql is correct:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("Test1")]
[InlineData("Test2")]
[InlineData("Test3")]
public void SelectWhereExpression_NameEquals(string name)
{
    using var sqlbuilder = GetSpecificBuilder();
    string sql = sqlbuilder.Select()
                           .Where(obj => obj.Name == name)
                           .Build().SqlCommand;

    var selectSql = SelectAllRecordsExpectedSql.Remove(SelectAllRecordsExpectedSql.Length - 1, 1);

    Assert.Equal($"{selectSql} WHERE (Name = '{name}')", sql);
}
```

The .Where() method takes as parameter the expression and it calls my SqlVisitor with that expression:

```
public virtual SqlBuilder<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    BuiltObject.Append(" WHERE");
    ExpressionToSQLVisitor<T> expressionToSQL = new(this);
    expressionToSQL.Visit(expression);
    return this;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's an expression that you're evaluating, what *is* it evaluating to, what do you *expect* it to evaluate to.  The whole point is to turn non-constants into constants.  If the expression is already a constant, it does nothing, and it's unclear what you even thing it would do.

Comment: `this.Visit(partialEval);` - result of evaluator is ignored.

Comment: @Servy then how should I use it? Because my local variables are detected as a Constant when they aren't, they are variables. I'll update the post above to show how I'm testing the code.

Comment: It's a job to tune skills? What is the goal of this "SQL" generation?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The purpose is replacing old legacy code that gets all values from a table and then using linq filters the list of values. To improve db performance I'm trying to build dynamic SQL queries translating Expressions into real SQL.

Comment: Get [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) and start using LINQ in 5 minutes. You have to fight with a lot of corner cases, parameters, SQL value conversions, mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @svyatoslavdanyliv but I prefer do it myself so I can learn better about Expression trees. The rest of my SQLvisitor it's working fine, the only thing left to sort out is the local variable resolving.

Comment: I'm learning this for 7 years, and actually, I'm one of the `linq2db` creators. You are on early start. Will prepare answer tomorrow, too late here.

Answer (score 0):

Will change a little bit your code. How do you plan to render values is up to you.
Main change is overriding `VisitConstant` in `ExpressionToSQLVisitor`.

```cs
protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
{
    if (node.Expression?.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
    {
        sqlBuilder.AddColumn(node.Member.GetFieldName());
        return node;
    }
    else 
    {
        var partialEval = Evaluator.PartialEval(node);
        if (!ReferenceEquals(partialEval, node))
        {
            Visit(partialEval);
            return node;
        }
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The member '{0}' is not supported", node.Member.Name));
}

protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
{
    sqlBuilder.AddValue(node.Value);
    return node;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I still have the same issue. The type of node.Value is an anonymous type like this: ...Repositories.Test.Builders.SqlBuilderTests+<>c__DisplayClass32_0') ;

Comment: So,  `Evaluator.PartialEval` do not evaluate member expression to Constant? If yes, I'll provide you with my evaluator.

Comment: Exactly, that seems to be the problem that the Evaluator doesn't evaluate the member expression into a constant.

Comment: In `Nucleon` library you can get normal evaluator: [PartialExpressionEvaluatorBase.cs](https://github.com/reaqtive/reaqtor/blob/main/Nuqleon/Pearls/LINQ/PartialExpressionEvaluator/Library/PartialExpressionEvaluatorBase.cs). Looks like it has no dependency and just copy/paste with small changes should work.

Comment: Alright I'll have a look into it, thanks.