# How to build expression tree for Contains<T>

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I'm following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891426/524861) to convert lambda expressions to partial SQL syntax.

However, I have problems parsing the expression for `Contains`. I added a method:

```
private bool ParseContainsExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
{
    MemberExpression member = (MemberExpression)expression.Arguments[0];

    var methodInfo = typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(int) });

    //TODO check if list contains value

    return false;
}
```

As I'm totally new to expressions, I don't know from where get the property name and value, and the list that contains the values I want to check against. Where are these properties and values stored within the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to process the [Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.method(v=vs.110).aspx), [Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.object(v=vs.110).aspx)(*expression that represents the instance for instance method calls or null for static method calls*) and [Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx)(*a collection of expressions that represent arguments of the called method*) properties of the [MethodCallExpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.methodcallexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Specifically for `Contains`, you need to avoid (or process differently if needed) the `string.Contains` method, and also handle `static` methods like `Enumerable.Contains` as well as instance methods like `ICollection<T>.Contains`, `List<T>.Contains` etc. In order to get the list values (when possible), you have to find some sort of a constant expression.

Here is a sample:

```
private bool ParseContainsExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
{
    // The method must be called Contains and must return bool
    if (expression.Method.Name != "Contains" || expression.Method.ReturnType != typeof(bool)) return false;
    var list = expression.Object;
    Expression operand;
    if (list == null)
    {
        // Static method
        // Must be Enumerable.Contains(source, item)
        if (expression.Method.DeclaringType != typeof(Enumerable) || expression.Arguments.Count != 2) return false;
        list = expression.Arguments[0];
        operand = expression.Arguments[1];
    }
    else
    {
        // Instance method
        // Exclude string.Contains
        if (list.Type == typeof(string)) return false;
        // Must have a single argument
        if (expression.Arguments.Count != 1) return false;
        operand = expression.Arguments[0];
        // The list must be IEnumerable<operand.Type>
        if (!typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(operand.Type).IsAssignableFrom(list.Type)) return false;
    }
    // Try getting the list items
    object listValue;
    if (list.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        // from constant value
        listValue = ((ConstantExpression)list).Value;
    else
    {
        // from constant value property/field
        var listMember = list as MemberExpression;
        if (listMember == null) return false;
        var listOwner = listMember.Expression as ConstantExpression;
        if (listOwner == null) return false;
        var listProperty = listMember.Member as PropertyInfo;
        listValue = listProperty != null ? listProperty.GetValue(listOwner.Value) : ((FieldInfo)listMember.Member).GetValue(listOwner.Value);
    }
    var listItems = listValue as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
    if (listItems == null) return false;

    // Do whatever you like with listItems

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is quite different from the example answer. You really need to inherit from `ExpressionVisitor` so that you can properly parse the tree.

Let's take this expression for an example:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "A" };
Expression<Func<string, bool>> a = (s) => myList.Contains(s);
ParseContainsExpression(a.Body as MethodCallExpression);

private bool ParseContainsExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
{
    expression.Object; //myList
    expression.Arguments[0]; //s    
    return false;
}
```

Note however, these are still *Expressions*, they are not actual values yet. You need to invoke the expression to get the values.

However, in our case - `myList` is actually a `ConstantExpression`. So we can do this:

```
((expression.Object as MemberExpression).Expression as ConstantExpression).Value; //myList
```

Which returns us the original list. Note that it's a *field* access, because the expression is compiled into a closure, which puts `myList` as a field in the closure class. As you can see, we have to make a *lot* of assumptions as to the type of Expression we're handling (that it's a field access and then a constant expression). You really need a fully-fledged visitor implementation to do this properly (which the linked answer describes)

Comment: Yes I'm using the full visitor implementation as described in the linked answer, but I would like to add `Contains` to it too.

Comment: Rob is saying you don't need reflection, you just need to get the list and the candidate from the expression and then call contains directly on the list.

Comment: In which namespace can I find `Dump()`

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Sorry - you can remove the `.Dump()` calls - they're left over from testing in LinqPad