# Replace the C# string which should execute in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, telerik

I have a string which is generated through `RADDataFilter` Filter Criteria. I want to execute the same condition with Where clause in SQL Server. How can I convert the following string through program?

```
   ((ADD_DTE IsGreaterThan 3/27/2016 12:00:00 AM) OR (ADD_BY StartsWith TEC) OR
 ((CHG_DTE IsLessThan 7/1/2016 12:00:00 AM) OR (CHG_BY Contains TEC))) AND 
((NOT_DES Contains new) OR (NOT_TXT IsEqualTo SQL))
```

to

```
    ((ADD_DTE >= '3/27/2016 12:00:00 AM') OR (ADD_BY LIKE 'TEC%') OR ((CHG_DTE <
 '7/1/2016 12:00:00 AM') OR (CHG_BY LIKE '%TEC%'))) AND ((NOT_DES LIKE '%new%') 
OR (NOT_TXT = 'SQL'))
```

I Have kept all the String `(Contains, StartsWith, IsGreaterThan, IsLessThan , IsEqualTo`) in dictionary. These string should be replaced with the equivalent SQL Operator and the value.

Another Thought: Is there anyway It can convert this LINQ to SQL in built method?

Please help me on this. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: RadDataFilter Link: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/raddatafilter/datafilter-end-user-manual

Comment: You linked to the silverlight docs, is that the version you are working with or are you working with the WPF or winforms version and you just did not use the correct link?

Comment: It's more than just replacing the operators. Most of these must also adjust the value. Where it gets really trick is you have a RadDataFilter with a clause like this: `(ADD_BY StartsWith T)EC)`. What does your filter look like if a text value contains a parentheses? Or if it contains the text for one of your operators?

Comment: Are you using any Linq2Entites library like Entity Framework? If so, there are better ways to do what you want, that is the way the RadDataFilter was designed to be used, building a filter for a `IQueryable<T>` object.

Comment: I am working this on Silverlight application, this link is correct.

Comment: Hi Joel, It does not contain any Parantheses. It is only a text in the value filed.

Comment: Hi Scott, I am not using any Lonq2Entites library. It is given by Telerik RadDataFilter control through this property, radDataFilter.ViewModel.CompositeFilter.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

The `radDataFilter.ViewModel.CompositeFilter.ToString()` is not going to work, you have lost to much info to reliably parse it, you will need to use [`radDataFilter.ViewModel.CompositeFilter.Descriptor.CreateFilterExpression(`](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/api/html/M_Telerik_Windows_Data_IFilterDescriptor_CreateFilterExpression.htm) then parse out the  resulting Expression. That parsing is what libraries like Entity Framework are doing internally to generate their queries.

Here is a function that will turn the filter designed by the control to a `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` that could be used with a `.Where(` clause on a `IQueryable<T>`. This code was written with the WPF version of Telerik, but I put in a comment what the silverlight version should be.

```
private System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>()
{
    var param = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    //In silverlight, the path would be this I think.
    //var filteredExpression = radDataFilter.ViewModel.CompositeFilter.Descriptor.CreateFilterExpression(param);
    var filteredExpression = radDataFilter.FilterDescriptors.CreateFilterExpression(param);

    if (filteredExpression is System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression)
    {
        //"CreateFilterExpression(param) returns "Expression.Constant(OperatorValueFilterDescriptorBase.UnsetValue)" when no filter is applied.
        //We just return true for all rows when that happens.
        return (x) => true;
    }

    return System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filteredExpression, param);
}
```

You will need to find a library or [write your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731905/how-to-convert-an-expression-tree-to-a-partial-sql-query), that can turn your `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` in to a query string.

Comment: Hi Scott, Instead of this I have looped through the Composite filters recursively. Thanks for the help you have provided.