# sql from expression trees C#

Tags: c#, json, expression

I basically have a generic class called DynamicServices. The dynamicServices will look like the following

```
class DynamicEntityServices<T>{
     T GetById(Guid Id) { // get from db using ado.net dal 
     List<T> Search(SearchCondition searchCondition) { // filtering the data from the dal
}
```

Now, that I have a json spec file [basically a json schema file that defines the dynamic entity and its property / types

During runtime, I want the consumer of my service to build and send me a search condition.

I currently have my SQLDAL implementation like the following

```
class DynamicEntityDAL<T>{
    List<T> Search(SearchCondition condition){
      StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
      foreach(var field in condition.Fields){
         query.Append(" "+field.Key+" like '%"+field.Value+"%' ")
```

and something similar to the above, I know that the above process is right because there are practical limitations of this. Please note that I would like to actually get an expression sent in from the caller of my dynamic service in the search condition and then I will construct the query as like below

```
var filterExpr = new Expression()...
var paramterExpr = new ParameterExpression("categorystatus",true); // not the right ones, but will look similar to this.
var condition = new SearchCondition{ SearchExpression = filterExpr };

In DAL, I can try to convert the above to SQL using some expression visitor like
`string filterClause = ConvertToSql(condition.SearchExpression);`
```

I can read and implement things, but as my json schema files are dynamic, I cannot use EF. Kindly suggest the right approach so that my library can get the expression from the caller of the service and also get it translated to T-SQL and query from db.

Comment: If you are just concerned with how to generate SQL from standard Expression Tress, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7933938/3745022) would be of use to you. If you want to know how to create that Expression Tree from your unspecified JSON, then you should provide more details - for simple queries you can create Expression trees manually, but if your JSON represents something more complex, then that would be a nontrivial task.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a piece of JSON that represents the expression for a `WHERE` clause of a user query, then here are the steps of converting that to SQL:

1. Convert JSON string to a Hierarchal object.
2. Convert the Hierarchal object to SQL.

Assuming you already have (1) done (it looks like you can create `Expression`'s, presumably from the JSON), then you just need to write something that recursively traverses the Hierarchal object and converts it to SQL, depending on the type of `Expression`.

You're going to probably need some notion of an explicit schema (tables and columns) somewhere to dynamically compute your `JOIN`'s, unless this is all in one table/view.  Additionally, if your schema's foreign key relationships creates a cyclic graph then you'll need to define relationships, in addition to tables and columns (which will help you specify which type of join unless you can assume `INNER` is always okay).  This will also help you when you want to change the SELECT columns and ORDER BY columns, when/if that becomes a need.

This is coming from someone who has written similar things multiple times in the past:

- This is very time-consuming and non-trivially to do correctly; it's better to find something that already does something similar enough to what you want, instead of writing this from scratch.
- Leverage as many existing frameworks as possible if there isn't something already out there for you that works.  For example, reusing Linq `Expression`s instead of rolling your own, which it looks like you've done that.

Good luck!