# Mix in raw SQL into Entity Framework Select

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a grid on a website that show a pre-select list a columns to users based on entity framework query

something like this

```
dbContext.Items.Select(i=> new {
    i.Name,
    i.description,
    ...
})
```

I want to give the user a option to have 1 custom column 
(its an internal system and i'm not worried about security)
here is a sample what i would like to do

```
    dbContext.Items.Select(i=> new {
         i.Name,
         i.description,
         CustomColumn = dbContext.RawSQL("SELECT TOP 1 [CreatedDate] FROM [Sales] WHERE ItemId = " + i.Name)
     })
```

That's the concept i'm looking for, so i can let the user type his RAW-SQL and I will pass it into the select based on user.

I need raw SQL because its the most dynamic for my use case. And it will allow me to use tables there are no entities available (like views and SP)

And in the other hand I don't want to use full raw SQL because other than that column I fully use EF, and it way more than just this sample, and I don't want to lose the benefits that EF offers

Comment: `That's the concept i'm looking for, so i can let the user type his RAW-SQL and i will pass in into the select based on user.` This is very wrong.

Comment: depends for what you need it, its not a public project

Comment: Public or not creating code that is wide open to sql injection is just horrible. Don't do it to yourself.

Comment: sql injection for who??? its an internal system that ppl have direct access to database

Comment: If they have access to the database why do you need an application to run queries? Regardless, others may see the code in here when writing another application and use the same style for something external. It is a very bad habit to get into.

Comment: thanks for the advise but im not here to explain the concept of the application & no, event if you can write raw queries not always its the most productive way to see the data, i want to know if its possible, not if its secure or best way

Comment: So you are just here to see if your approach, which is far less than ideal, is possible and don't care to learn a better approach. Got it. Have a great time with that.

Comment: Here is some documentation that explains how to do this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149752/discussion-between-cms-and-sean-lange).

Comment: EF does it best to hide generated Sql from the coder. I don't believe one can mix raw sql into EF-generated Sql. Even if you succeed not sure the code will survive EF version upgrade.

Comment: let me explain something looks like you guys are not getting, i'm not all crazy here with the idea of putting raw sql in EF, its fully supported, and even added better support lately with EF7, it has lots of good parts like using SP and more, BUT my question is if it can Mix and only use it for 1 column in select

Answer (score 0):

i just came across this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891426/4328664

looks like i will just need to implement a ExpressionVisitor class