# How to merge a method call under different switch cases to make the code generic or optimized?

Tags: c#, generics, switch-statement

I have a method which fetches the information of employee from database. The method is as below with a switch case

```
public void RetrieveEmployeeInfo(EmployeeInfoRequest request)
{
    EmployeeStandardInfoResponse response;
    int employeeId;
    switch (request.Type.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        case "employeeid":
            //Some Logic
            response = GetEmployeeInfoFromDatabase(EmployeeSearchType.ByEmployeeID, employeeId);
            break;
        case "emailaddress":
            //Some Logic
            response = GetEmployeeInfoFromDatabase(EmployeeSearchType.ByEmailAddress, emailAddress:request.Id);
            break;
        default:
            return null;
    }
    return response;
}
```

The signature of "GetEmployeeInfoFromDatabase" is

```
public EmployeeStandardInfoResponse GetEmployeeInfoFromDatabase(EmployeeSearchType employeeSearchType, dynamic value)
{
    //For simplicity I am returning employee info here
    return new EmployeeStandardInfoResponse();
}
```

Below are the supporting classes and Enum

```
public enum EmployeeSearchType
{
    ByEmployeeID = 1,
    ByEmailAddress = 2
}

public class EmployeeInfoRequest
{
    public int Id;
    public string Type;
}

public class EmployeeStandardInfoResponse
{
    public int employeeReferenceId;
    public string employeeDepartment;
    public string employeePfDetails;
    public string employeeName;
    public string employeeEmailAddress;
    public string employeeAddress;
}
```

How can I make the switch case generic so that I do not have to call method "GetEmployeeInfoFromDatabase" under every case ?

Comment: Simply store `employee` or `emailAddress:request.Id` (btw.: shopuld this be an optional, named parameter? It´s not predent in the methods signature) and thus won´t compile) in a variable and call the method after both switches. Anyway this sounds like a review and is likely to go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Apart from this I can´t see much trouble on your code. It´s easy to understand and gets the things done. What else do you expect?

Comment: @HimBromBeere You are right. Originally I made the call as optional but later on after modifications I though to use dynamic while calling  GetEmployeeInfoFromDatabase

Comment: Also, EmployeeSearchType (enum) is different in both cases. Therefore what I am looking for is that while making decision, I should be able to dynamically/generically change EmployeeSearchType.ByEmployeeID or EmployeeSearchType.ByEmailAddress

Comment: @ThementalistCoder  how you connecting to db - ado.net, entity framework ?

Comment: you could extract both the searchtype and the value into two variables and then call the method once with the two variables.

Answer (score 0):

Below is not full blown solution; but enough to help you what you want to achieve. Idea is : Depending upon user search criteria, create expression tree using lambda expression syntax. In your final method in repository, you can pass that expression and parse it (say to get DB sql query) for fetching info from DB.

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            GetEmployeeInfoFromDatabase((e) => e.EmployeeEmail == "UserProvidedEmailAdderessGoesHere");
        }

        public EmployeeStandardInfoResponse static GetEmployeeInfoFromDatabase(Expression<Func<Employee,bool>> exprssion)
        {
           /* parse this exression to build query*/
           /* use as it is if using entity framework*/
        }
    }

    class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Second/Third answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731905/how-to-convert-an-expression-tree-to-a-partial-sql-query)
stack over flow post beautifully describes expression to query translation logic.

You can go ahead and make it more re usable and generic further (not only limited to Employee entity)

```
public EmployeeStandardInfoResponse static GetEmployeeInfoFromDatabase<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> exprssion)
            {
               /* parse this expression to build query*/
               /* use as it is if using entity framework*/
            }
```