# DateTime lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I was testing the implementation in the thread answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891426/1468492 but I get an error trying to parse an expression with a `DateTime`, for instance: `t => t.Name == "NAME" && t.OpeningDate == DateTime.Now`.

Is this the right way to build a DateTime lambda expression? If I create an expression like `Expression<Func<Model, bool>> expression = t => t.Name == "NAME"` the result is correct.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Is your `OpeningDate ` a datetime object or only date? If it is only date then use `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` to compare

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `OpeningDate` is a `DateTime` and I can´t use `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` to compare

Comment: i dont think it will work t.OpeningDate == DateTime.Now. Perhaps you want DateTime.Today?

Comment: `DateTime.Today` not works. The error is in the `protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression m)` when try to parse `DateTime.Today` and the error is `Additional information: The member 'Today' is not supported`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can build `t => t.Name == "NAME"` expression, the next step is to combine it with `t.OpeningDate == DateTime.Now` by `Expression.And`. Try this code:

```
var t = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Model), "t");
var body = Expression.And(
    Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(t, "Name"), Expression.Constant("NAME")),
    Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(t, "OpeningDate"), Expression.Constant(DateTime.Now))
);
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Model, bool>>(body, t);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to improve current solution to support members, particularly you need to improve `VisitMember`. Now it just throws a `NotSupportedException`.

As a workaround you can just extract it first:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var expression = t => t.Name == "NAME" && t.OpeningDate == now;
```

In this case it would address a constant, not a member.

Comment: Adding `DateTime now = DateTime.Now` the `now`is converted to `System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression` not to `System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression`. Using the @AleksAndreev solution the Right expression is a constant. Any idea?