# Linq like predicate to sql string

Tags: c#, linq, orm

I want to make a function which should accept linq like expression based on model and property types of models and return a SQL string.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public static class MyControlClass
{
    public static string BuildSQL<TModel>(Func<TModel, bool> whereExpression)
    {
        return $"SELECT * FROM {nameof(TModel)} WHERE {whereExpression}";
    }
}

public main(){
    string sqlQuery = MyControlClass.BuildSQL<MyModel>(m => m.Year == 2021 && UserName == "Tester");
    
    //What I wish sqlQuery to be
    //SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE Year = 2021 AND UserName = "Tester"
}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I am aware of POCO and other ORM libraries and I have been trying and searching for more than 3 days now. I just cant find a solution.

Comment: Did you try the Entity Framework? It's all in it.

Comment: If your database supports linq-to-sql you shouldn't build your sql yourself.

Comment: @PalleDue I wonder how to make something not what I should or "shouldn't"

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen do you have any example of mentioned framework to use in my case and get the foreseen result?

Comment: Well, stated differently, @PalleDue says: you should let an ORM do the job for you. If you are aware of ORM libraries, does that mean you actually tried any of them?

Comment: @SecretaryOfEducation, perhaps this is a useful starting point: [Introducing LINQ to Relational Data - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/cc161164(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: @GertArnold I want to make my own ORM for example

Comment: Perhaps what you are looking for is in the series of [blog posts by Matt Warren](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattwar/linq-to-sql-the-mapping-engine), who created the first version of LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is not simple at all. And you have to deal with `Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> whereExpression`

Then you can visit this expression `ExpressionVisitor` for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891426/10646316) and generate SQL.

Or you can save your time with escaping strings, dates, ect., install [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) and just write:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{   
    // create options builder
    var builder = new LinqToDbConnectionOptionsBuilder();

    // configure connection string
    var options = builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

    using var db = new DataConnection(options);

    var query = db.GetTable<MyModel>().Where(m => m.Year == 2021 && m.UserName == "Tester");

    // will generate SQL
    var sql = query.InlineParameters().ToString();

    // will return list of items
    var items = query.ToList();
}
```