# Predicate to SQL through LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Is there a way to translate predicate(Func<T,bool>) using LINQ to SQL query or something similar to this?

Found nothing on internet or MS guides.

Comment: For translating predicate you have to use `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`. But without mapping information  it is bad idea to implement it by hands.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, thanks, but my goal is to create a basic CRUD and I want to make it without any side libraries or frameworks, just with basic linq, so i found this example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731905/how-to-convert-an-expression-tree-to-a-partial-sql-query/7891426#7891426

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORMs (like Entity Framework, linq2db, and others) in C# usually use expression trees and [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=net-7.0) to be able to translate the code into actual SQL queries, so they need `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, not just `Func<T, bool>`. If you are creating the predicate via lambda then compiler can also translate it to expression tree, i.e.:

```cs
Func<MyClass, bool> predicate = mc => mc.IntProp == 1;
Exppression<Func<MyClass, bool>> predicate = mc => mc.IntProp == 1;
```

Will work both well. So in some cases you can just change your method parameter and that's it.

Read more:

- [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)
- [What is the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
- [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) - interesting library which does some magic around LINQ

Answer (score 0):

Short awnser : no
Long awnser : yes... but actually no

There is no way to accuratly translate a programming language into another without the risk of the function and meaning being altered
(you could use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/) but even that is no longer mantained)

I would recommend you learning LinQ in order to safely translate it without mistakes.
You could also post you query so anyone like me or other more fitted members to help you out in the translation.